# how to read CSD register from eMMC using mmc-utils

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, beaglebone

We have beaglebone black based custom board with 512MB RAM and 4GB eMMC.

I was trying to read CSD register from the board however I am getting following error.

```
# mmc csd read /dev/mmcblk0
MMC/SD information directory '/dev/mmcblk0' does not exist.
```

When I checked the `mmc csd` command's help it says "device path should specify the csd file directory.

```
# mmc csd --help
Usage:
        mmc csd read <device path>
                Print CSD data from <device path>.
                The device path should specify the csd file directory.
```

So I tried below command as well,

```
mmc csd read /sys/class/mmc_host/mmc1/mmc1\:0001/csd
```

However it doesn't work. 
I don't know what should be passed as path spec.
I know i can read that sysfs file to get csd value, however i thought mmc-utils should parse it and display.

I am will look at mmc-utils code and update my findings here. meanwhile anyone knows let me know so that it is faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the path is correct, it should work if you remove the trailing `csd` from the path:

```
mmc csd read /sys/class/mmc_host/mmc1/mmc1\:0001/
```

Comment: If you don't want to have to figure out the "magic sys path" then you can use this shortcut: `mmc csd read /sys/block/mmcblk0/device`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively:

```
mmc extcsd read /dev/mmcblk0
```

Comment: Welcome on the SU! Command line copy-paste can be useful, but I think it would be better if you explain, how your command is different as the other answers.